# Multithreading with python?

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, python-2.7

I wrote a script to guess a pin, it kinda works but the script  ignores the sleep command, and also the command threading.lock() does not working. so can you look through my script and tell how  I can make my script better?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -w 
#
# 
import time
import random
import os
import threading
import sys


lock = threading.Lock()
def Random(name,repeat):
    lock.acquire
    while repeat != 0:
        Pin = random.randint(0,9999)        
        print "[+] Trying: %d"%Pin;time.sleep(3)
        if Pin == 5656:
            os.system("clear");print '[+] Pin Found: %d' %Pin;time.sleep(3)
            sys.exit()
        repeat-= 1

    if lock.acquire():
        lock.release()


def Order(name,repeat):
    lock.acquire

    while repeat != 0:
        Pin = random.randint(0,9999)        
        print "[!] Trying: %d"%Pin;time.sleep(3)

        if Pin == 5656:
            os.system("clear");print '[+] Pin Found: %d' %Pin;time.sleep(3)
            sys.exit()
        repeat-= 1



    if lock.acquire():
        lock.release()




def Main():
    Brute_1 = threading.Thread(target=Random,args=('Random_Guess',10))
    Brute_2 = threading.Thread(target=Order,args=('Order_Guess',10))
    Brute_1.start()
    Brute_2.start()


if __name__=='__main__':
    Start = raw_input("Press Enter To Start")
    while 1:
        os.system("clear");
        Main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop at the end of the listing will create two new threads every time through.  The `sleep` function is called by the new threads, not the main thread, so the main thread will go through the `while` loop as fast as it can.  That will generate new threads by the thousands, until the system crashes.  You *think* the sleep function isn't working but of course it is; it's just that every time you see a line printed on the console it's the first guess taken by a new thread.  I don't think that's what you want.  I don't know what you're trying to do so I can't help further.

Also as pasztorpisti hinted, `lock.acquire` is a function and needs to be called with function call syntax (`lock.acquire()`) or else nothing will happen.  Having said that, you need to clean up the high-level structure first.

Once you acquire a lock, other threads are blocked when they try to acquire the same lock.  The `time.sleep` function DOES NOT release the lock, so as long as Thread1 has the lock Thread2 cannot acquire it, even though Thread1 is sleeping.